# Contact form is not send after correct validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm using node.js for backend contact form and nodemailer for sending the message. My problem is that whenever I correctly fill inputs it still shows me an error that my inputs are not correct and it doesn't send the message. Thank you in advance

Here is my code:

Validation

```
function checkInputs() {
  const nameValue = name.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const numberValue = number.value.trim();
  const subjectValue = subject.value.trim();
  const messageValue = message.value.trim();
  const humanValue = human.value.trim();

  if (nameValue === '') {
    setErrorForName(name, 'Name cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessForName(name);
  }

  if (emailValue === '') {
    setErrorForEmail(email, 'Email cannot be blank');
  } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
    setErrorForEmail(email, 'Not a valid email');
  } else {
    setSuccessForEmail(email);
  }

  if (numberValue === '') {
    setErrorForNumber(number, 'Number cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessForNumber(number);
  }

  if (subjectValue === '') {
    setErrorForSubject(subject, 'Subject cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessForSubject(subject);
  }

  if (messageValue === '') {
    setErrorForMessage(message, 'Message cannot be blank');
  } else {
    setSuccessForMessage(message);
  }

  if (humanValue !== '4') {
    setErrorForHuman(human, 'Please answer the question above');
  } else {
    setSuccessForHuman(human);
  }
}
```

Message function

```
function sendMessage() {
  const formData = {
    name: name.value,
    email: email.value,
    number: number.value,
    subject: subject.value,
    message: message.value,
    human: human.value,
  };

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.responseText == 'success') {
      alert('Email sent');
      name.value = '';
      email.value = '';
      number.value = '';
      subject.value = '';
      message.value = '';
      human.value = '';
    } else {
      alert('Something went wrong!');
    }
  };

  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
}
```

submit function

```
export default function contactApp() {
  contactForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!checkInputs()) {
      alert('Please fix errors to submit.');
      return;
    } else {
      sendMessage();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your checkInputs() function, the function is not returning any thing but you are checking the validation status in condition

```
    if (!checkInputs()) { //to achieve this goal function must return either true or false
          alert('Please fix errors to submit.');
          return;
        } else {
          sendMessage();
        }
```

the corrected version of the code is following, just add return statement at the end in your checkInputs() function to tell that either of the concerned input is not ok.

```
    function checkInputs() {
  let flag = true;
  const nameValue = name.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const numberValue = number.value.trim();
  const subjectValue = subject.value.trim();
  const messageValue = message.value.trim();
  const humanValue = human.value.trim();

  if (nameValue === '') {
    setErrorForName(name, 'Name cannot be blank');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    setSuccessForName(name);
  }

  if (emailValue === '') {
    setErrorForEmail(email, 'Email cannot be blank');
    flag = false;
  } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
    setErrorForEmail(email, 'Not a valid email');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    setSuccessForEmail(email);
  }

  if (numberValue === '') {
    setErrorForNumber(number, 'Number cannot be blank');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    setSuccessForNumber(number);
  }

  if (subjectValue === '') {
    setErrorForSubject(subject, 'Subject cannot be blank');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    setSuccessForSubject(subject);
  }

  if (messageValue === '') {
    setErrorForMessage(message, 'Message cannot be blank');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    setSuccessForMessage(message);
  }

  if (humanValue !== '4') {
    setErrorForHuman(human, 'Please answer the question above');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    setSuccessForHuman(human);
  }
  
  return flag;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Zain, it works! I knew that I forgot something in the validation.